# Describing an air-conditioned room on a hot summer day

Tags: expressions

How to describe the feeling when you enter a room with running air-conditioner in a hot summer day?

Can I say, "Oh, it feels so cool in this room!" (suppose pleasant cool)
Or, "I feel a little cold, do you mind adjusting the temperature up a little?"

Comment: If it were a *pleasant cool*, you wouldn't ask to have anything adjusted . . .

Comment: Do you have any problem with the air conditioning? The answer depends on that! :) The question is unclear.

Comment: Your statements are fine.  You may also refer to the coolness as **air conditioning**.  "Oh, the **air-conditioning** is too high. Could you turn it down a bit?"

Comment: @EllieK What's meant be "Air conditioning is too high"? Too hot or Too cold?

Comment: @user2824371 I suppose it could mean either, but generally that would be interpreted to mean "it's too cold". However, user EllieK clearly defines *air conditioning* to mean "coolness". So, the coolness is too high, or too intense. In other words it's cold, which is what the asker states as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's cold, turn it down a bit.